# PhateR Crashing R

Tags: python, r, reticulate, seurat

I'm trying to run the tutorial for phateR:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/phateR/readme/README.html

but it keeps getting to the calculating kmeans step and crashing R entirely with an unknown fatal error.
I've tried troubleshooting with the steps in:

https://github.com/KrishnaswamyLab/phateR/issues/52

but still have the same problem.

```
reticulate::py_discover_config(required_module = "phate")
python:         C:/Users/harri/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/R-MINI~1/python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/harri/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/R-MINI~1/python39.dll
pythonhome:     C:/Users/harri/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/R-MINI~1
version:        3.9.6 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jul 11 2021, 03:37:25) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:/Users/harri/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python39/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.21.0
phate:          C:\Users\harri\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\phate\__init__.p
```

Would someone be able to help me please? Thank you.

```
data(tree.data)
reticulate::py_discover_config(required_module = "phate")
reticulate::import("phate")
library(phateR)
tree.phate <- phate(tree.data$data)
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the code you are using that is generating that error?

Comment: `
library(phateR)

data(tree.data)

tree.phate <- phate(tree.data$data)`

Comment: Can you edit your answer and put that in a code block in it instead of adding it as a comment?

Comment: Sorry I'm new to using stackoverflow, I've edited my post though.

Comment: That is not a problem. I am just a moderator trying to provide tips to improve your question so you can get better answers. However, I can't answer this one myself.